# How to get second highest and below value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, subquery

How to get all the values below highest value. i.e second highest, third highest and so on....

[image: Get 14 and 12]

I want to select id = 14 and 12. Condition is second and third highest id values where `section = 'abc'`

My Query is like this: `select id from tbl_front_post where id IN (SELECT id from tbl_front_post where id < max(id)-1 and section = 'abc')`

Note:  I can't write `id=15` so `id = max(id)-1` because id may changed at any time

Comment: Why negative marking?

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery to find the maximum value:

```
select id
from tbl_front_post
where id < (SELECT MAX(id) from tbl_front_post where section = 'abc') and
      section = 'abc'
-- order by id desc
-- limit 2     -- for 2nd and 3rd, or however many results you want
```

This would work well if the `id` column has unique values only for each section.  In this case, we would not have to worry about ties for the maximum `id`.

Comment: I need second highest and third highest and so on

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to do this.

```
SELECT id
FROM tbl_front_post
WHERE section = 'abc'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2, 2
```

`LIMIT x, y` means to return `y` rows starting from row # `x` in the order.

Comment: shouldnt the limit be ```1, 18446744073709551615```;
ie. except the first to the end

Comment: nice idea, but there can be any number of rows.. Now there are 3 rows having section = 'abc'. But number of rows can be chnaged any time.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_front_post
WHERE section = 'abc' order by id desc LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;
```

This will give you all rows with `section = "abc"`, except the first to the end.

**NB**: `18446744073709551615` is just a big number to indicate you want all rows to the end; [check the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#id4651990):

> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the
>   result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.